# Is there a way to add array objects to a class?

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, object

I am very new to this but I am trying to add object arrays to a class in android studio. I have created a "User" class that will be used to store information of each user. I need to create an object for each user, and set the appropriate variables (name, password and favourite color), and store this in  a data structure. As you can see in the code below ive been trying to figure out the best way to go about this but I am still unsure. If anyone can please help or give me any guidance it would be muchly appreciated.

```
public class User {

String user1[] = new String[3];
String user2[] = new String[3];
String user3[] = new String[3];
String user4[] = new String[3];
String user5[] = new String[3];

String user[] = {"Jason", "Sword", "Red"};

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change your structure a bit.

The class you have given us above isn't really a User, but a group of Users.  I suggest you rename the class accordingly, e.g. UserGroup.  'Users' would also work just fine, but if someone is skimming quickly through the code they might think they read 'User' instead and get muddled.  I am pretty sure I would!

Go and make a different class called User, which has a bunch of String fields in it for the different values you want to store, e.g.

```
public class User {
  String name;
  String weapon;

  public User(String name, String weapon) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weapon = weapon;
  }

}
```

Back in your UserGroup class, don't hold String arrays but actual Users, e.g.

```
public class UserGroup {

  User user1 = new User("Jason", "Sword");

}
```

Comment: Awesome that works great thank you sunrise! Is there a way I can store the user objects to a variable so I can access it from other activities? Because I would need to check if the user objects matches the user input.

Comment: My pleasure :)  It took me a while to get my head around how to build classes and separate things out properly.

You certainly can store the Users in one neat collection to be used elsewhere: Java Collections!  See here for an entry to the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html.  I would not advise using an Array, as you have to state the number of Users up front and then it's fixed.  Something like an ArrayList, however, would give you quite a bit more flexibility on how many Users there are at any one time.

Comment: So you think i should put the user objects into an ArrayList to access them in other activities?

Comment: That very much depends on you and your program.  If you want to reference a particular User elsewhere, you can instantiate that User from where it is needed and pass the variable reference around.  If you want to make all your Users in one place and have a way to pass them all as a bundle to be processed elsewhere, you will need some sort of collection.  ArrayList comes to mind due to its flexible size, but what you want to do with the bundle of Users will determine what structure is most appropriate for you.  If in double, give ArrayList a try and see if works or where it lets you down :)

Comment: Oh ok thank you! Its a kind of login app where I will need to check if the username and password the user has entered matches one of the user objects if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Android Studio, I suppose that you wanna make an app. So if that's the idea you must store user data in files because class is a logical construct. class works only at runtime. So when you use a class, after runtime it will destroy the user data which is practically of no use. It's better to use files and Objects and don't forget to use Secure Hash Algorithms for password.

Comment: Yes I understand that but its just for a task I need to do so it doesn't matter that it will be destroyed once the app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two Hash Map.
'UserAPass' is used to store name and password.
'UserAFavCol' is used to store name and favorite color.
Put both hash maps as static so that it can be shared among instances as per app usage.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class User {
static HashMap<String, String> UserAPass = new HashMap<String, String>();
static HashMap<String, String> UserAFavCol = new HashMap<String, String>();
    void addUser(String name, String pass, String col) {
        UserAPass.put(name, pass);
        UserAFavCol.put(name, col);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class User {
public User(String name, String password, String favouriteColor) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.favouriteColor = favouriteColor;
}

private String name;

private String password;

private String favouriteColor;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFavouriteColor() {
    return favouriteColor;
}

public void setFavouriteColor(String favouriteColor) {
    this.favouriteColor = favouriteColor;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    User users[] = {new User("Jason", "Sword", "red"), new User("Jack", "MyWord", "green")};
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much Jack. Do you know a way of going about how to check if a user has entered the same details as what is in the class?

Comment: Generally speaking, it doesn't make sense to check whether there are the same properties in a class. I guess you mean to judge whether there are duplicate user classes in the list. If this is the case, override the equal method of the user class and call the contains method of the list to know whether there are users with duplicate attributes